# Summation closed form for $k^{n^p}$

Tags: summation

Is there any closed form expression for

$$\large\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} k^{n^p} / \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} k^{-n^p}$$

I know that for $p=1$, this converges to $-k$. Is there any other known solution for $p>1$?

Comment: Huh? If $p=1$ then either the numerator or the denominator does not converge. Can you clarify this question?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : It's not just for $p = 1$, $\sum u_n$ and $\sum u_n^{-1}$ can never converge  simultaneously.

Comment: Yeah, was just using that one example. @JoelCohen

Comment: I don't even see a way to salvage this as a question about formal Laurent series or some such. Basically, the two series: $\sum_{n} z^n$ and $\sum_{n} z^{-n}$ both have analytic extensions to the $\mathbb C\setminus\{0,1\}$, and those analytic extensions have this property. But I'm not sure what you can do about analytic extensions of $\sum_{n} z^{n^2}$ and $\sum_{n} z^{-n^2}$, and there isn't a good theory of formal Laurent Series - at least, not allowing infinite terms in either direction.